# RGB to gray filter doesn't preserve the shape

Tags: numpy, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I have 209 cat/noncat images and I am looking to augment my dataset. In order to do so, this is the following code I am using to convert each NumPy array of RGB values to have a grey filter. The problem is I need their dimensions to be the same for my Neural Network to work, but they happen to have different dimensions.The code:

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
  return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])

Normal Image Dimension: (64, 64, 3)
After Applying the Filter:(64,64)
```

I know that the missing 3 is probably the RGB Value or something,but I cannot find a way to have a "dummy" third dimension that would not affect the actual image. Can someone provide an alternative to the rgb2gray function that maintains the dimension?

Comment: I think that you can use `reshape()` from numpy, if your goal is to have (64,64,1)
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: My goal is for it to have the same shape as the original image.

Comment: But you cannot, because grayscale image is a 1-channel image and rgb is 3-depth, Am I missing something?

Comment: I see.The thing is when I am flattening my images into vectors this could be problematic as the size of my neural network is 64x64x3.

Comment: Are you using transfer learning or an architecture from scratch?

Comment: I have built a relu->sigmoid architecture but have to stick to it for assignment purposes.

Comment: Is it a possibility to change the input to a one channell depth?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of applying that greyscale filter is to reduce the number of channels from 3 (i.e. R,G and B) down to 1 (i.e. grey).

If you really, really want to get a 3-channel image that looks just the same but takes 3x as much memory, just make all 3 channels equal:

```
grey = np.dstack((grey, grey, grey))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
  return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [[0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140],[0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140],[0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]])
```

Comment: Explaining what the code does and how it solves OP’s problem would make this a much better answer.